# Proxying connections from a set-top box

Tags: networking, proxy, charles-proxy

I am developing an app for a set-top box and for debugging purposes, I would like to intercept the network traffic coming out from the box. I don't have an option in the setup box to set up a proxy address. If there was an option to set up a proxy, I could hook it to Charles and intercept and modify the request on HTTP.

I have tried setting up a Hotspot on the Windows laptop and Charles only seems to intercept the requests from the main wifi network.

I have a OpenWRT router if that helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to capture local network traffic like this, including [ARP Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) (where you send fake ARP messages to convince the set-top box that you are actually the router, so it sends packets to you instead of the router, so you can then handle/forward them any way you like) or setting up a hotspot and connecting the set-top box to that, and using some kind of firewall software to redirect the packets there to your proxy.

In both those cases though, this is likely to be very difficult or impossible on Windows, which does not offer a lot of low-level controls required to do this. I would recommend using Linux with iptables, which is widely used for this, and does offer the control you'll need to modify raw traffic to redirect it to your proxy in these kind of network configurations.

In any case though, that may not help, since you're likely to run into a bigger problem: if you can't reconfigure the set-top box to use your proxy explicitly, then you probably can't reconfigure the CA certificates it trusts, which means you won't be able to intercept any encrypted (TLS) traffic such as HTTPS. It depends on what you're trying to do, but in many use cases this means that setting up an HTTP proxy like this is not very useful.

Your other option is to use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). This should be able to show you traffic on Windows, because it's not an HTTP proxy (unlike Charles & similar tools). Instead of actively handling the traffic, it just passively monitors all packets that pass through your machine. You won't be able to modify traffic, and you probably won't be able to see inside encrypted connections, but it will show you all raw traffic immediately, which might give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options depending upon how much of the environment outside of the set top box (STB) you own.

**Nota Bene**: You don't say that you need to alter the traffic, so I'll just focus on getting you visibility of it.

- The first step is to pickup a cheap wifi/switch (such as those from Microtik), connect it to your normal switch, add the STB to it, and also configure a [SPAN port](https://www.reddit.com/r/mikrotik/comments/gsxorb/how_to_pass_all_traffic_through_an_ether_port_for/) (which will mirror all the traffic to you).
- The next step is to run up [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) so that you can see what is entering and leaving the STB. Obviously you will only get deeper visibility into the traffic for the unencrypted flows.
- If you own the destinations that the STB is connecting to, you can now [import the TLS keys](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS) into wireshark, which will give you access to the encrypted flows too.